# Is ROM Manager compatible with the Galaxy Nexus?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, rom-manager

I looked a ROM manager called [ROM Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5rb3VzaGlrZHV0dGEucm9tbWFuYWdlciJd) but it is listed as incompatible with my Samsung Galaxy Nexus.

Does ROM Manager support the Galaxy Nexus? If not, what are the alternatives?

Comment: Where are you seeing that it's not compatible? ROM Manager works fine on the Galaxy Nexus (I have it on mine right now). The app's developer even owns a GNex, as I recall.

Comment: Error : This app is incompatible with your Samsung Galaxy Nexus.
Samsung Galaxy Nexus
This item cannot be installed in your device's country.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Galaxy Nexus is supported from a device/hardware standpoint, but it may not be available in your region for some reason. If that's the case, you can instead get ROM Manager [directly from the developer's website](http://www.clockworkmod.com/rommanager). There are also ClockworkMod recovery downloads on that page.

If, for whatever reason, ROM Manager proves to be unusable or unsatisfactory, there are a few alternatives currently available:

- [GooManager Beta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.s0up.goomanager&feature=search_result)
- [ROM Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.liberty.toolbox&feature=search_result)

Comment: I would vote up but I don't have enough rep.